# HTTP 500.19 error Local IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015

I have problem with IIS. I googled it but couldn't find a solution. I tried to change my config file but it didn't work. If you want any additional information I'm gladly add it. Thank you for all.

**Here is my IIS settings**
[image: Here is my IIS settings]

**Here is the image of when I try to debug my website from visual studio 2015 (And my awesome paint skills :) )**
[image: Here is the image of when I try to debug my website from visual studio 2015 (And my awesome paint skills :) )]

**Here is the image of my visual studio settings for web**

[image: Here is the image of my visual studio settings for web]

Comment: It is very likely that you have URL Rewrite module tag or other similar tags in your web.config, but did not install the required module on Windows via MSI.

Comment: @Lex Li 
Oh I solved it finally. Yeah you were right. I reinstalled rewrite module and TADA! it works now. Thank you :D If you add this comment as a reply I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is some internal design of IIS configuration system that in rare cases such an error page comes without the actual line number for the real error (note the line 0 in the error page).

Based on my investigation so far, the most obvious cause can be a missing section definition in IIS schema folder, which probably breaks the XML parser.

The common module that leads to such missing section can be out of band IIS modules shipped as separate MSI downloads from Microsoft.

URL Rewrite module is probably the most likely culprit in this case, as people use it so often, but it is not included in the default IIS installation. Note that it can still be caused by other OOB modules.

A better way to analyze the problem, is to run Jexus Manager (http://jexusmanager.com) which features an XML written by me, which can tell exactly what section definition is missing.

Comment: It solved the problem. Thank you for this awesome answer :)